# Duration token android

Tags: java, android, token

I was wondering, for a phone app using token authentication. What would be the maximum duration of the token ? 
It's an app that might be used daily by the user, and I don't know how long should be the token's validity. 
I was thinking of setting like 2 days of duration and when it expires, give to him a new token with a new expiration date. Is it a good way or should I ask the user to login again every X day ?

Comment: no, the user should not have to login again. refresh the token using some kind of refresh token. Look for example at oauth.

Comment: @luk2302 I am new to token sorry, but when i have my access token expiring, how can i create a new one with the expired one ?